# Devices without Firmware OTA. Why and how to check?

Tags: updates, ota-update

Sellers often specify on their site if a device support Firmware OTA updates, or not.

Two questions:

1. If the OS is original android - why wouldn't it support Firmware OTA updates?
2. After I received a phone - how can I immediately check if it supports Firmware OTA updates, without waiting for the next update?

Thanks!

---

Examples for phones:

With OTA:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Original-Xiaomi-Redmi-3S-Official-Global-Firmware-OTA-Upgrade-Octa-core-Mobile-Phone-Snapdragon-430-4100mAh/32697748798.html

Without:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Global-Version-Xiaomi-Mi-A1-MiA1-Mobile-Phone-4GB-RAM-64GB-ROM-Snapdragon-625-Octa-Core/32830253938.html

Scroll all the way down and look for this message:

```
Pls read me before you make order.

we will open the original box to check the phone and install Multi-language ROM
and Google play store.
Official rom will be prefered.
if custom translation may does not cover all the menus.
Not support OTA update.                    <--<---<------
We may update the ROM, so the OS version may different as the screenshots.
```

P.S.

In local stores I noticed it mostly about whether the device was bought from an official distributor, or from a parallel distributor.

Comment: Why the down vote?